# Combination of latest versions of vite, vue, @vitejs/plugin-vue and vite-plugin-virtual-mpa is not including asset urls in build output

Tags: vue.js, build, vite, assets, multi-page-application

#### Problem

###### In Brief

In my current project with old libraries, I am having '1 high severity vulnerability' as can be seen with 'npm audit'. So I want to update the libraries to latest verions. But updating them breaks my build.

###### + Detail

I am building a multi-page Vue project with Vite by using a Multi-page-plugin: vite-plugin-virtual-mpa and vite-vue plugin: @vitejs/plugin-vue. But after the build, the generated html files are not having links to generated asset files. Have a look at images below.

How it should be:
[Code with proper asset urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pEYU.png)

How it is:
[Code without asset urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Mxx.png)

( I made a minimum reproducible version of the project. https://github.com/shivamrawal19/testmpa It has both old and new version of package.json & package-lock.json files, so you can test it in both cases. )

#### What I've tried

- I tried to update packages one by one to see, when the issue is coming, but no matter which library I update first, it fails.
- - I found out that even if I run `npm install` on just old `package.json` ( i.e. without old `package-lock.json` ) it is generating wrong `package-lock.json` file which inturn generates wrong `node_modules` and wrong `npm run build`.
  - So only if I use both old `package.json` and old `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install` then only it works. So the old `package-lock.json` is somehow built properly.

*I am not sure about which package is causing error so I am posting this on StackOverflow, instead of respective package's github issues page.*

I think the issue is with some library as my code seems quite simple and bug-free to me, but do correct me if that's not the case.